# LessCss, call a method with default parameters

Tags: css, web, less

Given this extreme example:

```
.somemethod(@a:1, @b:2, @c:3, @d:4, @e:5, ... @z:26) {
        ... 
}
```

If I decide to call the method and only want to change the **@x** and use all the defaults up to **@x** and after **@x**, is it possible to pass something to tell less to use the defaults?

Otherwise I would have to redundantly repeat the argumetns, and given that those defaults might change, I would have to update them everywhere every time.

Any clues?

Comment: i.e. `.somemethod(@x: zoo);`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Great!